# Reset/remove JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java

I was trying to resole an issue with Android SDK instalation, and followed a recomendation to set up JAVA_OPTS: 
`set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402772/failed-to-install-android-sdk-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-a

Then I tried to receive different errors, e.g.

```
C:\Users\Daria>sdkmanager --list
Error: Could not find or load main class '- 
XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '- 
XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
```

I guess, it was a mistake, and I want to remove JAVA_OPTS or return to initial state. How can I do it?

Comment: `set JAVA_OPTS=`